# SPM Xcode test fails because bundle couldn't be loaded

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, xctest, matlab-spm

I cannot run **tests in Xcode** when working on a **pure SPM package**, testing on **Mac** (macOS 13).

Running the tests of the package with `swift test` in the Package root folder **works!**
Only Xcode testing of the the Swift package does not work properly.

It fails telling me:

```
[loading] Cannot find executable for CFBundle
```

```
The bundle “<test target name>.xctest” couldn’t be loaded because its executable couldn’t be located. Try reinstalling the bundle.
```

When I look at the output in `DerivedData` I can see all the binaries and bundles having been created.

Somehow Xcode doesn't have the correct rights to be able to load these bundles.

#### Steps to reproduce:

- create a brand new package from Xcode
- run `CMD + u` to run the tests (make sure the selected device is `Mac`(your machine))

**⚠️ The tests fail with the before mentioned error message. ⚠️**

#### System information

- Macbook Pro M1
- macOS Ventura (13.4.1 (22F82))
- Xcode 14.3 (14E222b)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to the problem, because I was thinking about the "rights issue" that Xcode might have.

**Enabling `Full Disk Access` fixes the problems!**
Just go to `System Settings on macOS > Privacy & Security > Full Disk Access > Add Xcode to the list and enable the switch`